# How can I get a file in a Go web project for testing and production?

Tags: go

I am currently working on a web project where we use Go (with martini) a backend. It contains a reverse-geocoder which maps coordinates to city names. To do so, the reverse-geocoder has to read a `cities.csv`.

The structure is

```
handlers/city/create.go
services/geo/reverse.go
services/geo/cities.csv
main.go
```

Now the `main.go` is started to start the web service. The handler `handlers/city/create.go` makes use of `services/geo/reverse.go` to get 
the city with `cities.csv`.

The problem is to get the `cities.csv`.

### What I've tried

#### plain filename

However, when I only use `csvFilename := "cities.csv"`:

- the tests work
- the handler doesn't work as go assumes `/home/me/go/src/github.com/githubuser/backend/cities.csv`

#### adjusted filename

When I adjust the filename to be relative to the root (`csvFilename := "services/geocalc/cities.csv"`), the tests fail. They assume `/home/me/GitHub/go/src/github.com/githubuser/backend/services/geocalc/services/geocalc/city-names-geocoordinates.csv`.

#### args[0]

This doesn't work either:

```
filename := filepath.Dir(os.Args[0])
filedirectory := filepath.Dir(filename)
csvFilename, _ := filepath.Abs(path.Join(filedirectory, "cities.csv"))
```

Now the tests fail with `/tmp/go-build210484207/github.com/githubuser/logbook-backend/services/geocalc/cities.csv`

#### runntime caller

```
_, filename, _, _ := runtime.Caller(1)
filedirectory := filepath.Dir(filename)
csvFilename, _ := filepath.Abs(path.Join(filedirectory, "cities.csv"))
```

works for the tests, but in "production" (testing with http-queries) it assumes `/home/me/GitHub/go/src/github.com/githubuser/backend/handlers/packets/cities.csv`

#### os.Getwd()

Version 1

```
filedirectory, _ := os.Getwd()
csvFilename, _ := filepath.Abs(path.Join(filedirectory, "cities.csv"))
```

fails in production with `/home/me/GitHub/go/src/github.com/githubuser/logbook-backend/cities.csv`.

Version 2

```
filedirectory, _ := os.Getwd()
csvFilename, _ := filepath.Abs(path.Join(filedirectory, "services/geo/cities.csv"))
```

Fails in the test with `/home/me/GitHub/go/src/github.com/githubuser/logbook-backend/services/geo/services/geo/cities.csv`

Comment: why not pass this as a command line argument with an absolute path?

Comment: ... or an environment variable, or a key in a config file for that matter?

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer Sure, that would be possible. But it would be simpler if I could get the directory of the current package. Isn't that possible with Go?

Comment: have you tried instead of os.Args[0] to get the CWD with os.Getwd? that's usually how I do it.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer I've just tried it. One version works while running the server, the other works while running the tests with `go test ./...`. No version works for both. The problem seems to be that `go test ./...` runs the tests from another directory. Is it possible to run all tests from the "usual" directory?

Comment: well, you can always set some env var for the root working directory and read it from all tests. e.g. "MYWD=\`pwd\` go test ./..."

Comment: Why not write a function which tries each method in turn? First look for env variable or command flag, then try using `os.Args`, then `runtime.Caller`, then `os.Getwd`. Return as soon as one of them finds a match. Though at my work we build from a common $GOPATH, bundle that up, and deploy to the same path (including sources), so we just use `runtime.Caller()` (helps to have a build server for this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that I can use the `GOPATH` environment variable. It is always set (see [The GOPATH environment variable](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH)) and therefore no additional work:

```
filedirectory := os.Getenv("GOPATH")
csvFilename, _ := filepath.Abs(path.Join(filedirectory, "src/github.com/gituser/backend/services/geo/cities.csv"))
csvfile, err := os.Open(csvFilename)
```